# Insert encrypted token (Uint8Array) to mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, encryption, amazon-kms

I'm trying to save encrypted token in mongodb. I'm using AWS KMS to encrypt the token. Then I save it in mongo. Buw when I try to fetch it back it returns as an object with unknown characters, and not as an ArrayBuffer. So when I try to decrypt it, KMS says
['argument must be ArrayBuffer'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESbhF.png)

The object in mongo look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4igE.png).
I tried to insert the encrypted key exactly how it return from [KMS encryption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqNFg.png).

This is the  [returned object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBvCd.png) from mongoDB.

My question is how to properly save/fetch the encrypted data in/from mongoDB?

Thanks for any help

**My Code**

I use aws-sdk V3 for the was operations.
Encryption & Decryption:

```
export const encryptToken = async (token) => {
    var uint8array = new TextEncoder().encode(token);
    const encryptCommand = new EncryptCommand({
        KeyId: KMS_KEY_NAME,
        Plaintext: uint8array,
    });
    const response = await client.send(encryptCommand);
    return response.CiphertextBlob;
};

export const decryptToken = async (cipher) => {
    const decryptCommand = new DecryptCommand({
        KeyId: KMS_KEY_NAME,
        CiphertextBlob: cipher,
    });
    const response = await client.send(decryptCommand);
    const token = new TextDecoder().decode(response.Plaintext);
    return token;
};
```

Insert & Get:

```
const insertOpenaiKey = async ({ orgName, orgId, openaiKey }) => {
    const encryptedKey = await encryptToken(Key);
    const objToInsert = {
        orgId,
        orgName,
        encryptedKey,
    };
    await insertDatabase(COLLECTION_NAME, objToInsert);
    return "Key inserted successfully!";
};

export const getOpenAIKey = async (orgId) => {
    const docs = await (
        await queryDatabase(COLLECTION_NAME, { orgId })
    ).toArray();
    if (!docs.length) {
        throw new Error(`Credentials not found for ${orgId}`);
    }

    return docs[0].key;
};
```

Comment: You could show us the code instead of images

Comment: You are right, sorry for that. I added the code